# Problems with std::cin and isdigit in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, cin

When I run the code and enters for instance 1 in the terminal it goes to the 'else' condition and breaks. But I'm providing it with a digit so I have trouble understanding why it behaves like that. Could someone help clarify?

```
int main() 
{
  vector<int> positions;
  int p;
  
  for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
    
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> p;
    
    if(isdigit(p)){
      positions.push_back(p);
    } else
    {
      cout << "Please provide numbers from 0 to 100!" <<"\n";
      break;
    }
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the program in your debugger yet?

Comment: Since `p` is an `int`, then `cin >> p` will read only `int` values. The call to `isdigit` makes no sense for a generic `int` value. The [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) function check if a ***character*** is a digit. I.e. it check for e.g. `'1'`, which is very different from the integer `1`.

Comment: In other words, you'll be surprised to learn that `isdigit(3)` is false.

Comment: Moreover, the `std::isdigit` function only checks if a single character is a single digit, it can't check if e.g. a string is all digits. Meaning it can't handle multi-digit numbers like `26`.

Comment: Thx everyone, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function is defined for the character, it would be true if you wrote `isdigit('1').`

Also `isdigit(49) = true`, because in ascii 49 is digit 1, so `isdigit(49) = true;`

check the reference of `isdigit()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/